# printing a statement when a submit button is clicked

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question regarding the session. I want the correct answet to be displayed once the user clicks on the submit button. I used isset for that but the correct answer is displayed even when the button is not clicked. Is there any problem with my code??

```
$sql13=mysql_query("select * from image WHERE toUser='".$_SESSION['email']."' order by id desc");
$score2=mysql_fetch_array($sql13);
$answer3=$score2['answer'];


if(isset($_SESSION['panswer']))
echo " The correct answer is : $answer3";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you have the variable set from previous tests.  Use an explicit comparison to make sure that the variable is not only set, but also equal to the expected value:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['panswer']) && $_SESSION['panswer'] == '1')
  echo " The correct answer is : $answer3";
```

The code you have provided is inadequate - no where do I see where you display your form, handle POST data, or set/unset the session value. So, this is only a best guess using the materials you have provided.

Comment: Thank you your answer was very useful I put another condition.

Answer (score 0):

If your button is clicked then a GET or POST request should be (most probably) be made. You are checking against a SESSION variable thus the condition will be true if the variable is set - regardless of the button being clicked or not.

You could add a second condition which 'checks' if the button was clicked or not.

Tip: You could add a hidden variable which is sent via GET or POST and check if that variable is set (along with your existing condition) - that is one way to do it.

Comment: Yes it worked when I put a second condition where the value is checked. Thank you.